# UINavigationBar color changes unexpectedly

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

In my current UINavigationController, the viewControllers stack looks like this.
1 -> 2 -> 3.  Before transitioning from the 2nd to the 3rd controller however, I pop the 2nd one first so that when the 3rd controller is popped, the 1st controller is on top.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES ] ;
```

But somehow doing this changes the navigationBar's color from the original blue default to the black style.  Explicitly setting the barStyle to UIBarStyleDefault in the new controller's viewWillAppear or viewWillDisappear has no effect.  What's stranger, if I set the barStyle at all, even the 1 -> 2 transition will cause the bar color to change to black.

By the end of writing this post, I realized that the following code fixed it.

```
navBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault-1;
```

Why would I need to subtract 1 from the default to actually obtain the default color?

Comment: more importantly, how on earth did you discover this?

Comment: In viewWillAppear, I noticed that setting barStyle to UIBarStyleDefault resulted in UIBarStyleBlack, which is +1 in the enum, so I figured it was off by one.  I haven't tried testing this in a separate project yet.

Comment: What does NSLog(@"%i", UIBarStyleDefault); say? You might have somehow got yourself in the situation where you code and the cocoa navigation controller library have been compiled with a different version of the header file that defines this enumeration? (I have no idea how this might happen!)

Answer (score 1):

I would not pop the second, just push the 3rd. And when you dismiss the 3rd use

```
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This for me reaches back and cleans up the stack and leaves me on controller 1 without showing controller 2, with all normal attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem as well. I don't have a formal answer but I fixed it in my way:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
UIColor *navColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:0.742778 green:0.0181208 blue:0.0271147 alpha:1];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:navColor];}
```

I wish someone could propose a better answer.